# Is this unit test redundant?

Tags: unit-testing

These days I write more unit tests than I did not long ago due to having realized I did not do it properly (I thought I was doing pretty well, but was actually missing out on a lot of tests). I am a bit unsure if I am over-doing it though.

Take the following Asp.NET MVC controller method declaration as an example:

```
[HttpGet]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(EditOrganizationViewModel editOrganizationViewModel)
```

If the model state is invalid I want the method to return a `ViewResult` with the same `EditOrganizationViewModel` that was passed in to the method (editOrganizationViewModel).

So I write the following three tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void EditPost_InvalidModelState_ReturnsViewResult()

[TestMethod]
public void EditPost_InvalidModelState_ReturnsEditComplianceViewModel()

[TestMethod]
public void EditPost_InvalidModelState_ReturnsSameEditComplianceViewModel()
```

The second test feels redundant due to the third test since it is implicit. The second test should not ever be able to fail while the third test passes. Do we still need it?

If the answer to the question is "No, we do not need it.", then we should be able to remove the third test for the same reasons if we add a test that checks that the properties of the view model has not been changed by the controller:

```
[TestMethod]
public void EditPost_InvalidModelState_ReturnsEditComplianceViewModelWithSameName()
```

The only reason I can see keeping those "seemingly redudant" tests are the fact that, although they may be redudant now, they may not be in the future. A pretty strong reason to keep them, one that I had not thought of until just now. I think I just convinced myself to keep them, but I would like to know what people think. Chances are I have missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is debatable and also depends on the motivation and  reasoning. All your points are very valid, and I would do pretty much the same. For example, keep the tests even they have some redundancy, i have a pretty strong reason to keep them.

**For:**

Also take a look at this way..
Your tests names are very descriptive which provide exactly whet the system under test (SUT) does as a specification/documentation. So even there is overlap between tests, these tests are good for a new person to understand what the SUT does.

Even if a test cannot exist without another (as you have in your 3 tests), there is no harm keeping them as long as they tests completely different things. It is your specification (sort of)

**Against:**

It is a simple natural rule and even more true for Unit Testing, that you may want to remove any duplication or redundancies. 
The tests are very important, but at the same time, it is extra code that you have to maintain. So if we are not mindful we add lots burden down the track to maintain these tests.

Generally speaking try to aim one change for one failing test. If you make a code change, multiple tests are failing, you can look at removing some redundancy. There is a concept in Unit Testing that you should only test one thing in a test. This is very true, however it does not imply that you would only Asserts a single thing. As long as your Unit Test verify a logically related operation, it still test a single aspect of your system under test(SUT).

You test methods names are very descriptive, which is a very good thing. This means that you planning to Unit Test only a single thing - which should be. When you write tests in this way if you still find that there is a redundancy remove your redundant tests. If you do TDD (Test Driven Development), this part of the process that you would remove redundant code/tests.

**Conclusion:**

Try to have some balance between For vs Against, BUT lean towards not to have redundant tests.

Comment: Although I have a lot left to learn I have to say that everything you wrote sounds very reasonable to me. Seems like it basically comes down to experience, so I will just keep coding along for now, probably err on the side of too many tests so that I can get a better feeling for when too much actually is too much.